how to on the dark mode of the stack overflow
how to on the dark mode of the stack overflow
It's my first day on stack overflow and as a newly user of stack overflow website ,I am facing some issues ,so if anyone has know how to on the dark mode of it then pls respond on it.
Thankyou!

https://stackoverflow.com/users/preferences/28062910

@ceejayoz "28062910" is OP's user ID so won't work for other readers. Use "current" instead: https://stackoverflow.com/users/preferences/current

Would be nice if SO gained an accessible toggle for this in the header or footer like most other modern sites.

You can set your theme preference (dark mode) here: https://stackoverflow.com/users/preferences/
